# Use media break points for white space?

Tags: css, web, bootstrap-4, whitespace

Should I use media break points for whitespace on the right and left of my page or is there a better / ready to be implemented solution for this in bootstrap? I looked around the documentation but no fruitful outcome, please assist me

Comment: Whats the problem you are trying to solve? I feel like this post is half of a conversation lol. help us help you

Comment: @zgood I am making a webpage, I added 15% Margin on right and left, but that isn't responsive since there are no media break points so it looks abysmal on small screens like mobile, so to solve this should I use media queries and change margin at different screen widths or is there some better way?

Comment: You could use media queries, but you might not need to. Depends on what your code looks like. Would be helpful to show use an example.

Comment: yes I would say that would be a good use of media queries

Comment: Here's a sniff https://del.dog/usoqubohuz

Comment: This is the media queries I made: https://del.dog/arozozicon

Please let me know of any improvements I could do :)

Comment: That's kind if what container is for. It's centered in the middle on larger screens (a lot of whitespace on left/right) and then scales to full-width on mobile screens leaving a small padding of 15px on each side.